# Limiting points of elementary set

Tags: nt.number-theory, gn.general-topology, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I consider the following set

$$A:=\left\{  \frac{3mn}{2(m^2+mn+n^2)}; m,n \in \mathbb Z; \text{ and }m,n \text{ are not both zero}\right\}$$

Is it possible to identify the closure of $A$ in the reals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set $x=n/m$, rational dense in the reals, so the closure of $A$ is the image
of the function $f(x)=3x/(2(x^2+x+1))$, so the interval $[-3/2,1/2]$.